# Paredit and transpose code blocks

Tags: emacs, transpose, paredit

If I have the following s-expression:

```
(if true (this) (that))
```

And I want:

```
(if true (that) (this))
```

How does paredit helps to transpose `(this)` and `(that)`?

Comment: See `transpose-sexps` (`C-M-t`) in the Emacs manual, node [Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "paredit" is, but in stock Emacs you can place the
point between `(this)` and `(that)` and hit <kbd>C-M-t</kbd> which runs
the command [`transpose-sexps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html):

> Like C-t (`transpose-chars`), but applies to sexps.
>
> Unlike `transpose-words`, point must be between the two sexps and not
>   in the middle of a sexp to be transposed.
>
> With non-zero prefix arg ARG, effect is to take the sexp before point
>   and drag it forward past ARG other sexps (backward if ARG is negative).
>   If ARG is zero, the sexps ending at or after point and at or after mark
>   are interchanged.